# how to name two classes, one plural and one singular of the same thing

Tags: naming

Say, I need two classes:

class #1: `componentGenerator`, given one component, it generates what needed.

class #2: `componentsGenerator`, given an array of components, it does some logic and then calls class #1 to generate for each one of the components.

I prefer not to name the classes `componentGenerator` and `componentsGenerator` because it's easy to miss the `s`.

What would you suggest to name the two so it won't be confusing?

Comment: Why not put them in the same class? It seems the purpose is generating components, so it's just two methods of the same single-purpose entity.

Comment: I am agree with @nvoigt . You can create a single class and inside that you can handle any number of componets.

Comment: @nvoigt, generally, that's correct and that would be the best option. In my case, I prefer to separate them into two classes because of two main reasons. reason 1) size. each one of the classes is big in terms of lines of code and is more readable to have them seperated. reason 2) cohesion. all methods needed for class #1 use the same properties and all methods needed for class #2 use different properties.

Comment: Well, if they are that different, then you should be able to come up with a name that is better than just a generic "component generator". But there is nothing in your post that would help us to find one for them, so I don't think you will get a satisfying answer here. The best guess we could make would be "ComponentGenerator" and "*SomeLogic*ComponentGenerator".

Comment: That's what I was trying to do but in my case, class #2 doesn't do anything special other than instantiating class #1 and calling its `generate` method. The reason why this class is big is that it had to do some calculations in order to come up with the properties to pass to class #1.